# Set Builder Notation Possible Empty Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's say you have a set $A= \{ v_{i}\mid i\in I \}$ where I is the empty set, $I=\left \{  \right \} $. Would the set $A$ become the empty set as well or would the expression not make sense?

Comment: First option, $A$ is the empty set

Comment: I appreciate your answer! Thank you!

Comment: you are very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{v_i\mid i\in\emptyset\}$ is a constructor for an empty union.   $\bigcup_{i\in\emptyset}\{ v_i\}$.   An empty union is an emptyset.

We require an empty union to work as follows:$$\forall A:\Big[ \bigcup_{i\in A\cup \emptyset}\{v_i\} = \bigcup_{i\in A}\{v_i\}\cup\bigcup_{i\in\emptyset}\{v_i\}\Big]$$

or $\forall A: \{v_i\mid i\in A\cup\emptyset\}=\{v_i\mid i\in A\}\cup\{v_i\mid i\in\emptyset\}$

Thus if this works for whatever is in $A$, the empty union must be empty.

---

Note 1: $\forall A~\forall B~:~\{v_i\mid i\in A\cup B\}=\{v_i\mid i\in A\}\cup\{v_i\mid i\in B\}$

Note 2: $\forall A~:~ A\cup \emptyset = A$

Comment: This actually answers another question I was going to ask! Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

The set-builder and subscript notation may be obscuring the essential logical relationships here. What we have here is an unspecified function (let's call it $V$) mapping set $I$ to an unspecified set (call it $S$).

$$V: I \to S$$

The set $A$ would be the range of the function $V$.

$$\forall x: [x\in A \iff x\in S \land \exists i: [i\in I \land [V(i)=x]]$$

We assume that the set $I$ is empty. If we also assume that $A$ is non-empty, we will be obtain the obvious contradiction .